# What is wrong with my /give command? 1.12.2

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

Something is wrong with my command. It is telling me `Data tag parsing failed: Expected non-empty key at: {ench:{id:32,lvl:500},<--[HERE]`

Here is the command I input:

```
/give @p diamond_pickaxe 1 0 {ench:{id:32,lvl:500},{id:34,lvl:9999}.{id:35,lvl:10}]}
```

Comment: Is the command you have here exactly as it is in your command block? Because if so, you have a period instead of a comma between enchantment 34 and 35 in your list which may be causing your issue

Answer (score 3):

You have 3 enchantments on your pickaxe, and each of those enchantments should be separated by a comma. In between your second and third enchantment, you instead have a period.

There is also a missing opening square bracket that designates the array of enchantments you want to place on the item.

The correct syntax would be:

`/give @p diamond_pickaxe 1 0 {ench:[{id:32,lvl:500},{id:34,lvl:9999},{id:35,lvl:10}]}`

Comment: Oh man, thanks bro! Was wondering why the same command wasn't working on 1.13, but I think this answer also answered that.

Answer (score 0):

Like @gigazelle said, it could be that, but if you have bedrock edition, then it won't work, as bedrock only allows you to have up to a certain level. (Depending on what the highest level you can get in survival is.)